# How can I edit a column when I double click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, edit, double-click

I am using a table to view some of the data, the table looks like below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Imthi</td>
        <td>30000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to edit the salary column in the above table when I double click that column. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I cant give a full answer because editing table rows would involve a bit of of code depending if you want Static or dynamic changes to tables. You will need to us a JS Plugging, something like this http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/

Comment: You can use the contenteditable attribute.

Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012823/how-to-make-html-table-cell-editable

Answer (score 4):

[DEMO](http://webplums.com/temp/demo/)

Check the link. used Ajax

---------DESCRIPTION------
**common.php**

```
<?php
// array OR retrieve values from database and store it as array
$EmployeeArray[1] = array('id'=>1,'name'=>'John','salary'=>30000);
$EmployeeArray[2] = array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Imthy','salary'=>20000);
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<script>
function editColumn(Id)
{
var params  = 'option=edit&Id=' + Id ;
var DivId = 'edit_' + Id;
ajax_function('ajax_edit.php', params, DivId);
}

function saveColumn(Id)
{
 var value = document.getElementById('salary_'+Id).value;
 var params     = 'option=save&value=' + value + '&Id' + Id ;
var DivId = 'edit_' + Id;
ajax_function('ajax_edit.php', params, DivId);
}
</script>

<?php
require_once('common.php');
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($EmployeeArray as $k=>$v)
{
$Id = $v['id'];
$Name = $v['name'];
$Salary = $v['salary'];
echo '
<tr>
    <td>'.$Id.'</td>
    <td>'.$Name.'</td>
    <td ondblclick="return editColumn(\''.$Id.'\');">
    <div id="edit_'.$Id.'">'.$Salary.'</div></td>
    </tr>
';  
}
?>

    </table>
```

**ajax_edit.php**

```
  <?php
   require_once('common.php');
   $option = isset($_REQUEST['option']) ? $_REQUEST['option'] : '';
   $Id     = isset($_REQUEST['Id'])     ? $_REQUEST['Id']     : '';

   switch($option)
  {
  case 'edit': // Display Text box
$value = $EmployeeArray[$Id]['salary'];
echo '
    <input type="text" id="salary_'.$Id.'" value="'.$value.'"  style="width:50px;" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="return saveColumn(\''.$Id.'\');" />';
  break;

  case 'save': // Save to Database
$value = $_REQUEST['value'];
echo $value;
  break;
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ondblclick="return editColumn(\''.$UniqueId.'\');"
```

use Ajax to call a page edit.php

```
edit.php
---------
```

Show text box with value, SAve and Cancel Button

```
save.php
---------
```

**click Save** - call the ajax function pass the Id and Value to this page
Use query to update

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example I can think of:

JS:

```
var salary = 30000;

document.getElementById('salary').innerHTML = salary;

function divDblClick(target){
    var new_salary=prompt("Please enter your salary", salary);
    salary = new_salary;
    document.getElementById(target.id).innerHTML = salary;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Imthi</td>
        <td id="salary" ondblclick="divDblClick(this)"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In your code, you would want to initialize an array for all the values in the table, instead of a single variable "salary".

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5dta/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use contenteditable attribute (html 5). But it's not double click.

Look at [How to make HTML table cell editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012823/how-to-make-html-table-cell-editable)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bFLmg/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable>I'm editable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I'm not editable</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose can be achieved by using

> contenteditable="true"

But I prefer making an "Edit" button (rather than double-click) which turns the complete table > tr > td(s) as editable. And than a "save" button which takes all the data from table (tr > td) and than sends an ajax request.

To elaborate:

1. Make "Edit"  to make them all editable (contenteditable="true")
2. Make "Save"  to take data from table and send to server.
3. Turn contenteditable="false" again after request has been send.

This is how I do it, rest is up to your specific approach.