# Making table cells editable on click

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a table which get its data from database. Now what I actually want to do is that when ever user clicks on a cell of any row, **the data in cell should be editable.** I am unable to figure it out to how to do that and also is there any way when user is done editing then I can **save the changes in my database**. Any suggestion are greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012823/how-to-make-html-table-cell-editable?rq=1

Comment: @gbestard
thank you :) 
its now editable... is there any way when user is done editing then i can save the changes in my database ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to start out with using JQuery and simple HTML.Gives you a good starting point

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
input{
    display:none;
    height:100%;
}

table{
    height:100px;
    width:300px;    
}

table td{
    width:50%;   
    height:100%;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr td').on('click', function(){
        $('input[type="text"]',this).css('display','block');
    });    
});
```

I have cooked up a fiddle for you.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7v2xpnzr/)