# How can I add edit button in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dolgozók felvitele</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="urlapcss.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="reg" action="felvitel1.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dolgozók</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="username1">Név<em>*</em></label>
                        <input id="username1" type="text"  name="username1"/>
                    </li><li>
                        <label for="address">E-mail<em>*</em></label>
                        <input id="address" type="text" name="address" />
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
            <a href="fooldal.html">Vissza</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
               $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Dolgozók"); 

               echo '<br><br><table id="table">';   
               echo'<th>ID</th><th>Név</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Edit</th>'; 

               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
               {

               echo'<tr>';
               echo '<td>'.$row['ID']. '</td>' ;
               echo '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
               echo '<td>'.$row['Email'].'</td>';
               echo '<td>'. "<input class='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='update' />". '</td>';
               echo'</tr>'; 


               }

               echo '</table>'; 
 ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I want to edit rows in this table, and I don't know how can I do this. Thank you! Maybe should I create an another php file for edit or use javascript? Let me know if you know the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, @Géza Horváth this [article](http://codewithawa.com/posts/php-crud-create,-edit,-update-and-delete-posts-with-mysql-database) maybe helpful for at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with table cells editable you can put input type="text" inside the  tag.
Else you can use bootstrap framework. It provides 
 You can easily find about this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012823/how-to-make-html-table-cell-editable).
Or you could see bootstrap 4 documentation.
Here best codepen example by *ash blue*. Please refer his code

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');

$('.table-add').click(function () {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function () {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  
  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  
  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    
    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();   
    });
    
    data.push(h);
  });
  
  // Output the result
  $EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

.table-editable {
  position: relative;
  
  .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

.table-up, .table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #00f;
  }
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #0b0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <p>Through the powers of <strong>contenteditable</strong> and some simple jQuery you can easily create a custom editable table. No need for a robust JavaScript library anymore these days.</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>An editable table that exports a hash array. Dynamically compiles rows from headers</li> 
    <li>Simple / powerful features such as add row, remove row, move row up/down.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
</div>
```

So you have to use these as well as php to again upload edited cells. Remember you need php to fill table with data.