# how i do edit html table design in textarea editor

Tags: php, textarea, editor

i have table html code in a var like

```
$table = "<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
";
```

is there a way to edit it in a simple textarea editor (without toolbar) but Does not appear like a source code , appear like design or templat and Then I will save it with a database with php form .

```
<textarea id="textarea_editor"><?php echo $table; ?></textarea>
```

Example :

[image]

Comment: Is the Example how you want to see the display in the textarea?

Comment: Do want to just edit the data, like change Mark to Marcus etc and add rows?

Comment: Look here for editable tables.<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012823/how-to-make-html-table-cell-editable> II doubt you can make your textarea parse and display the HTML string passed to it for display.

Comment: thanks @bcperth  i already make it with froala editor

Answer (score 0):

```
"<" replace "&#60;" and   ">" replace "&#62;"

<? 
    $table = "<table style=\"width: 100%\">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ";
    $tab = str_replace(str_replace($table, "<", "&#60;") , ">" ,"&#62;"); 

?>
<textarea id="textarea_editor"><?php echo $table; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks , but i do not understand . that is not a problem - i want textarea editor to edit table code

Comment: thank you sir , i already make it with froala editor , thanks agine