# Hiding tags in textarea but the effects of tag should be implemented

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a possibility where I can hide all tags in text area and display the value inside the tags but the functions of every tags should be implemented

```
<div id="myForm">
    <textarea rows="15" cols="100" id="html">
        <?php 
            echo"<table>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Firstname</th>
                     <th>Lastname</th> 
                     <th>Age</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Jill</td>
                     <td>Smith</td> 
                     <td>50</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Eve</td>
                     <td>Jackson</td> 
                     <td>94</td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>";
         ?>
     </textarea>
 </div> 

 <script type="text/javascript">

     $("#myForm").ready(function(e) {
         var text = $('#html').val();
         var cleanText = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

         $('#html').val(cleanText);
         e.preventDefault();

     });

 </script>
```

Comment: This is not possible, you can use content editable tag instead of textarea...

Comment: hide tags inside text and and display  value inside tags? can you be more clear with the question?

Comment: like rich text editor? @KunalKhatri

Comment: @Nezir display the value and hide the tags. Just like displaying a content in a webpage but this time is should be displayed inside the textarea.

Comment: Just make your textarea a div and give it below props...and you're done...
<div contenteditable="true"></div>

Comment: as @KunalKhatri said use `<div contenteditable="true">` instead of textarea, check the jsbin example https://jsbin.com/dosuvaf/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @KUMAR but I will use text area for method post in a form to submit it in database...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this if you use div instead of textarea is this what you want?

```js
$("#myForm").ready(function(e) {
var text = $('#html').val();
//var cleanText = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

$('#html').val(text);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myForm">
<div  contenteditable="true" id="html">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th> 
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td> 
<td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td> 
<td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I need text area for a form to submit it in db

Comment: you can submit also div, just give it a name and on form submit you will have content of div on server side

Comment: does it really work? I tried it before but it didn't.

Comment: yes, why wouldnt work, I mean div content is only element with some value. Nothing too special, textbox value is also element, I mean I dont work with php so I cant write you a correct sample now, but as you use textarea on form with submit do the same with div, just add to dive name and maybe id and try submit form to server and on server side in php you will see that div content and then you can save it wherever you wish (any table field)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make a editable table, what it seems like you want to have. Look at this [How to make HTML table cell editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012823/how-to-make-html-table-cell-editable)

If you just want to use the grid of the table and not show whats in the table, use the class type 'hidden'